# Supervisorctl successfully starts, but cannot stop

Tags: supervisord

When I start supervisorctl, it runs fine without issue. However, when I try to stop it or run status, I get this error:

```
# supervisorctl -c supervisor/stage.conf status
error: <class 'xmlrpclib.ProtocolError'>, <ProtocolError for 127.0.0.1/RPC2: 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR>: file: /var/www/envs/stage/lib/python2.7/site-packages/supervisor-3.0a10-py2.7.egg/supervisor/xmlrpc.py line: 474
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Install a stable version of supervisord, instead of an unstable alpha release.

Answer (score 1):

Put two new parameters into config belongs to your process with your process name

```
[program:<stage>]
...
stopasgroup=true
stopsignal=QUIT
```

Make sure supervisor has updated your config:

`sudo supervisorctl reread`

`sudo supervisorctl update`

Answer (score 0):

Check your user and password settings in /etc/supervisord.conf.

Comment: Having the same issue, I don't have any user nor password in the conf. are these required? I am running supervisord as root. any help is appreciated. thanks